# Use active cell to retrieve data

Tags: excel, vba

I have managed to get my VBA to use active cell to retrieve date and department number on my table. I am using this for advance filtering. I would like help in shortening up my code, the way I am going it would take quite a few lines. I have tried to add a message box that would say “No NCR” if cell valve = 0. I would also like message "Click on cell in table" if button is selected and the active cell is not in table range.

```vb
Sub select Range()

If ActiveCell.Address = "$B$7" Then
Range("O6").Value = Range("B5").Value
Range("Q6").Value = Range("A7").Value

ElseIf ActiveCell.Address = "$B$8" Then
Range("O6").Value = Range("B5").Value
Range("Q6").Value = Range("A8").Value

ElseIf ActiveCell.Address = "$B$9" Then
Range("O6").Value = Range("B5").Value
Range("Q6").Value = Range("A9").Value

End If
End Sub
```

[Table Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0AxK4.jpg)

Comment: A) Would help if you add the rows and column headers to your screenshot. B) what do you mean when you say “cell is 0?” and C) what is the table range?

Comment: Ricardo I have changed the table picture to show rows and column headers. I also changed "cell is 0" to value = 0. Looks like we have a couple solutions below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use `Select Case` structure to manage relevant cases, in proper order:

```
Sub selectRange()

    Select Case True
        Case Intersect(ActiveCell, Range("B7:M12")) Is Nothing
            MsgBox "Click on cell in table"

        Case ActiveCell.Value = 0
            MsgBox "No NCR"

        Case Else
            Range("O6") = Cells(5, ActiveCell.Column).Value
            Range("Q6") = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "A").Value
    End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: This is awesome, just what I wanted. It is great that people take time to help others. Now I need to finish getting the advance filter working and add this to our dashboard.   Thanks, Mark

Answer (score 0):

Intersect can identify if the ActiveCell is within your table. The row and column of the ActiveCell can deliver the department and month.

```
Sub selectRange()

    if not intersect(activecell, range("B7:M12")) is nothing then
        Range("O6") = cells(5, activecell.column).value
        Range("Q6") = cells(activecell.row, "A").value
    else
        msgbox "not in table"
    end if

End Sub
```

A Worksheet_SelectionChange could accomplish the same thing without a button.